# How to get numeric value from array

Tags: arrays, calculations

I'm struggling to get the numeric value out from arrays using the `arrayjobx` package. My goal is to store a list of values in several arrays, then when display them in a table be able to show the sum (per row / column). I would use a counter to calculate the sum, but I'm not managing to get out the numeric value stored in the `array`, to use it in `\addtocounter` to calculate the sum.

Here is a short example:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}

\begin{document}

\newarray\First
\newarray\Second
\newarray\Third 
\readarray{First}{10&8&3}
\readarray{Second}{1&7&8} 
\readarray{Third}{1&5&16}
\newcounter{ExpOneTotal}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Experiment & a & b & c & TOTAL \\ \hline 
Exp 1 & \First(1) & \First(2) & \First(3) &  \\ 
Exp 2 & \Second(1) & \Second(2) & \Second(3)  & \\ 
Exp 3 & \Third(1) & \Third(2) & \Third(3) & \\ 
TOTAL & & & & \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\First(1)

\the\numexpr \First(1) \relax 

\addtocounter{ExpOneTotal}{\numexpr \First(1) \relax}

My counter is: \theExpOneTotal~ instead of \First(1)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`\First` is not expandable and can therefore not be used in `\numexpr`.
The package [`arrayjobx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/arrayjobx) provides the following alternative:

`\check<arrayname>` extracts the desired value and stores it in `\cachedata` that can now be used in `\numexpr` and other places:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}

\begin{document}

\newarray\First
\readarray{First}{10&8&3}
\newcounter{ExpOneTotal}

\First(1)

\checkFirst(1)\cachedata~=~\the\numexpr\cachedata\relax

\addtocounter{ExpOneTotal}{\cachedata}

My counter is: \theExpOneTotal~=~\First(1)

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With calculations of row and column sums:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\newarray\First
\newarray\Second
\newarray\Third 
\readarray{First}{10&8&3}
\readarray{Second}{1&7&8} 
\readarray{Third}{1&5&16}
\newcounter{ExpTotali}
\newcounter{ExpTotalii}
\newcounter{ExpTotaliii}

\def\AddTotal#1(#2){%
  \csname check#1\endcsname({#2})%
  \cachedata
  \addtocounter{ExpTotal\romannumeral#2}\cachedata
}

\newcounter{ExpTotalSum}
\newcounter{ExpSum}
\makeatletter
\def\ExpSum#1(#2){%
  \setcounter{ExpSum}{0}%
  \begingroup
    \@for\I:=#2\do{%
      \csname check#1\endcsname(\I)%
      \addtocounter{ExpSum}{\cachedata}%
    }%
  \endgroup
  \theExpSum
  \addtocounter{ExpTotalSum}{\value{ExpSum}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
Experiment & a & b & c & TOTAL \\
\midrule
Exp 1 & \AddTotal{First}(1) & \AddTotal{First}(2) & \AddTotal{First}(3) &
  \ExpSum{First}(1,2,3) \\ 
Exp 2 & \AddTotal{Second}(1) & \AddTotal{Second}(2) & \AddTotal{Second}(3) &
  \ExpSum{Second}(1,2,3) \\ 
Exp 3 & \AddTotal{Third}(1) & \AddTotal{Third}(2) & \AddTotal{Third}(3) &
  \ExpSum{Third}(1,2,3) \\ 
\midrule
TOTAL & \theExpTotali & \theExpTotalii & \theExpTotaliii &
  \theExpTotalSum \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result table]

With alignment of the numbers via package `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\newarray\First
\newarray\Second
\newarray\Third 
\readarray{First}{10&8&3}
\readarray{Second}{1&7&8} 
\readarray{Third}{1&5&16}
\newcounter{ExpTotali}
\newcounter{ExpTotalii}
\newcounter{ExpTotaliii}

\def\AddTotal#1(#2){%
  \csname check#1\endcsname({#2})%
  \addtocounter{ExpTotal\romannumeral#2}\cachedata
  \global\let\CD\cachedata
}

\newcounter{ExpTotalSum}
\newcounter{ExpSum}
\makeatletter
\def\ExpSum#1(#2){%
  \setcounter{ExpSum}{0}%
  \begingroup
    \@for\I:=#2\do{%
      \csname check#1\endcsname(\I)%
      \addtocounter{ExpSum}{\cachedata}%
    }%
  \endgroup
  \addtocounter{ExpTotalSum}{\value{ExpSum}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{c*{4}{S[table-format=2]}}
\toprule
Experiment & a & b & c & TOTAL \\
\midrule
Exp 1
  & {\AddTotal{First}(1)}\CD
  & {\AddTotal{First}(2)}\CD
  & {\AddTotal{First}(3)}\CD
  & {\ExpSum{First}(1,2,3)}\theExpSum \\ 
Exp 2
  & {\AddTotal{Second}(1)}\CD
  & {\AddTotal{Second}(2)}\CD
  & {\AddTotal{Second}(3)}\CD
  & {\ExpSum{Second}(1,2,3)}\theExpSum \\
Exp 3
  & {\AddTotal{Third}(1)}\CD
  & {\AddTotal{Third}(2)}\CD
  & {\AddTotal{Third}(3)}\CD
  & {\ExpSum{Third}(1,2,3)}\theExpSum \\ 
\midrule
TOTAL & \theExpTotali & \theExpTotalii & \theExpTotaliii &
  \theExpTotalSum \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result table with aligned numbers]

Answer (score 4):

You can use more flexible methods; `arrayjobx` is unnecessarily complex and `expl3` methods are much more powerful.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setarray}{O{;}mm}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { g_alexb_array_#2_seq }
  \seq_gset_split:cnn { g_alexb_array_#2_seq } { #1 } { #3 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\getfromarray}{mm}
 {
  \seq_item:cn { g_alexb_array_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_gset_split:Nnn { c }
\cs_set_eq:NN \inteval \int_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{ExpOneTotal}

\begin{document}

\setarray{First}{10;8;3}
\setarray{Second}{1;7;8} 
\setarray{Third}{1;5;16}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Experiment & a & b & c & TOTAL \\ \hline 
Exp 1 & \getfromarray{First}{1} & \getfromarray{First}{2} & \getfromarray{First}{3} &  \\ 
Exp 2 & \getfromarray{Second}{1} & \getfromarray{Second}{2} & \getfromarray{Second}{3}  & \\ 
Exp 3 & \getfromarray{Third}{1} & \getfromarray{Third}{2} & \getfromarray{Third}{3} & \\ 
TOTAL & & & & \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\getfromarray{First}{1}

\the\numexpr \getfromarray{First}{1} \relax 

\addtocounter{ExpOneTotal}{\numexpr \getfromarray{First}{1} \relax}

My counter is \theExpOneTotal{}; should be \getfromarray{First}{1}.

\setcounter{ExpOneTotal}{%
  \inteval{
   \getfromarray{First}{1}+
   \getfromarray{Second}{1}+
   \getfromarray{Third}{1}
  }
}

My counter is \theExpOneTotal{}; should be
  \inteval{
   \getfromarray{First}{1}+
   \getfromarray{Second}{1}+
   \getfromarray{Third}{1}
  }

\end{document}
```

As you see, with `\inteval` you don't even need to set up a counter, because the computation can be done on the fly.

In the `\setarray` command the delimiter is customizable, you can do

```
\setarray[&]{First}{10&8&3}
```

if you prefer (or even change the token for the default value of the `O` argument).

[image]

You can even use floating point values, using `\fpeval` instead of `\inteval` (requires loading the `xfp` package).